# Correct syntax for solr QueryElevationComponent to pass IDs

Tags: solr

If any of you are trying the solr QueryElevationComponent and passing the Id's to elevate certain documents there is a small typo in the documentation.

The correct param name is elevateIds but in the docs it has elevatedIds

Answer (score 0):

The correct param name is elevateIds but in the docs it has elevatedIds